# Ember.js Redirect to Template

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a list of matches, and when I click one, I want to display the match. I know that I can do a Master-Detail style page, where when I click one, I can see the outlet somewhere on the same page, but that is not what I want.

I want it so that when I click on a link, it goes to an entirely new page for the match. I'm not really sure how to go about doing that.

Here is my route for `#/matches` (in coffeescript)

```
App.MatchesRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    App.Match.find()
)
```

Here is my `matches.handlebars`

```
<div id="matches">
  {{#each match in controller}}
    {{#linkTo "match" match class="panel six columns"}}
      Match between {{match.player.name}} and {{match.opponent.name}}
    {{/linkTo}}
    <br />
  {{/each}}
</div>

// I know that if I have this outlet, it will render `match.handlebars`
// right here, but I want it to be it's own page.
// {{outlet}}
```

I've only been working with Ember for a few days, and all of the examples I've found use Master-Detail views.

Please let me know of any other information I can provide from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**<Edit date="March 11th 2013">**

I've pushed a [**this repository in GitHub**](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/Ember-Contact-Management-ConceptUI). This is a conceptual app that uses `renderTemplate` somewhat the way you're describing.

**</Edit>**

In your child route, use the [`renderTemplate`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) hook in order to tell your application to render a specific template in a specific `{{outlet}}`. Example:

[Source Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/gETyr/)

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('matches', { path: 'matches' }, function() {
        this.route('match', { path: 'match/:match_id' });
    });
});

App.MatchesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Match.find();
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        model = App.Match.find();
        controller.set('content', model);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('matches', {
            into: 'application'
        })
    }
});

App.MatchesMatchRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Match.find(params.match_id);
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('match', {
            into: 'application'
        })
    }
});
```

This `MatchesMatchRoute` is setup to render its template (`matches/match`) into the `application` template. And since there is only one `{{outelet}}` this template (see handlebars below), we don't have to specify anything:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>App</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="matches">
    <h2>Matches</h2>
    <ul>
    {{#each match in controller}}
        <li>
            {{#linkTo matches.match match}}
                {{match.title}}
            {{/linkTo}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="match">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
</script>
```

If you have a scenario with multiple outlets, you have to hame them, like in the handlebars below:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>App</h1>
    {{outlet main}}<br />
    {{outlet nested}}
</script>
```

Then your routes will have to specify the outlet as well. Example:

[Source Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/hes8F/)

```
[...route code...]
renderTemplate: function() {

    this.render('content', {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'main'
    });

    this.render('buttons', {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'nested'
    });

}
[...route code...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the incredibly detailed answer. I'll take a closer look this evening when I have time to work on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can cause a template to render into a different template's outlet by using the `renderTemplate` hook when defining the route (see the guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/)

For your example it might look like this:

```
App.MatchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ into: 'matches' });
  }
});
```